# Google oauth2 with google plus: authenticate with backend server

Tags: javascript, django, oauth-2.0, python-social-auth

I am using the following tutorial to sign in a user on client side using Javascript:
https://developers.google.com/+/web/people/

The code given on the webpage works fine, but I want to obtain the access_token of logged in user, so that I can send it to my Django backend to authenticate the user.
I can get the access token by monitoring the Network requests using Google Chrome browser, but I don't understand how can I get the token programmatically.

I saw this post but it didn't help:
https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

If I use this piece of code:

```
function onSignIn(googleUser) {
  var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
  ...
}
```

With the code on first link, it does not get called.
Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a gist of the solution:

> https://gist.github.com/nikssardana/4739f700961cbcf2d2e31afdcfa8a143

After so many attempts, I realized that I was sending the `id_token` instead of `access_token`. [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth) says that we should send the `id_token` for authentication with backend, but for some reason `social_django` accepts `access_token`.